# Error in getting Data into Crystal Reports from two tables of Sqlite Database in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, crystal-reports

I am facing problem while pulling data from two tables of Sqlite database into Crystal Reports. I am using Strongly Typed Dataset. The code works fine in vb.net but on crystal reports it shows blank fields. Here is my code.

```
 Da = New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT in_No,inv_ProductName FROM Invoice,Inv_Detail WHERE inv_InvID=in_No", Conn)
        Rpt = New ReportDocument
        Da.Fill(Ds, "Report")
        Rpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Reports\rpt" & ReportName & ".rpt")
        Rpt.SetDataSource(Ds)
        CRV.ReportSource = Rpt
        CRV.Show()
        CRV.Refresh()
        Ds.Clear()
        Da.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself. Just changed the SetDataSource from DS to DS.Tables("Report"). It worked for me.

```
Da = New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT in_No,inv_ProductName FROM Invoice,Inv_Detail WHERE inv_InvID=in_No", Conn)
    Rpt = New ReportDocument
    Da.Fill(Ds, "Report")
    Rpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Reports\rptReportName.rpt")
    Rpt.SetDataSource(Ds.Tables("Report"))
    CRV.ReportSource = Rpt
    CRV.Show()
    CRV.Refresh()
    Ds.Clear()
    Da.Dispose()
```